# different page different color

Tags: html, css

Im trying to design this webpage with multiple pages. For example, when you scroll to the about page, its a different background color than the contact page. However, so far I only got the title of each page color. My webpage is where you scroll down it lands onto another page. I tried

```
#name{background-color:#ffffff;}
#Portfolio{background-color:#d5f4e6;}
#about{background-color:#fefbd8;}
#ContactMe{background-color:#ffffff;}
```

in the css style page based on its id. Any clue on how to get the different background color on different pages

html code:

```
  <body id="Portfolio"></body>

  <body id="about"></body>

  <body id="Contact Me"></body>
```

Comment: provide your HTML code, please. You want the background-color changes when scrolling or its by default ?

Comment: i believe both since when u click on the navigation bar, it will direct you to the page on the screen, or when you scroll you will see that you are in a different category page html code is above, i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "multiple pages" it means "separate pages in separate files!" like "aboutpage.html" or "contact.html". In this case you can work with "body" tag:

```
<body id="about">
```

but then you said "when you scroll to the about page" that means "a page with different section that you can use like this:

```
<p id="about"></p>
<p id="contact"></p>
```

or

```
<div id="about"></div >
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Comment: yea, i just changed it. now its only the title colored, not the rest of the body description

Comment: i think you use something like ajax or JS for load pages.. that means you load a "body" tag inside another! test your pages directly like this: "yourdomain.com/aboutpage.html"

Answer (score 0):

You should specify that the elements containing your targets are 100vh height. With your (original posted) code you can do it like that:

```
body > div {min-height:100vh;}
```

This css will catch the container-* div that you use in the code you provide. I recomand continue learning the basics. Start here https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/HTML

Enjoy code!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a same page scroller, you should add

```
#Portfolio,#about,#ContactMe {min-height:100vh;}
```

To your css.

If you can provide the exact code its much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

simple code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
startFromtop=$(".start").position().top
aboutFromtop=$(".about").position().top
contactFromtop=$(".contact").position().top
endFromtop=$(".end").position().top-100
$(window).scroll(function(){
windowformtop=$(this).scrollTop();
if(windowformtop>=startFromtop && windowformtop<aboutFromtop){
$(document.body).css("background-color","white")
}
else if(windowformtop>=aboutFromtop && windowformtop<contactFromtop){
$(document.body).css("background-color","red")
            }else if(windowformtop>=contactFromtop && windowformtop<endFromtop){
             $(document.body).css("background-color","green")
}else if(windowformtop>=endFromtop){
$(document.body).css("background-color","blue")
}

})
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
 div{height:700px;border:2px solid red;}
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="start">Start</div>
<div class="about">ABOUT</div>
<div class="contact">CONTACT</div>
<div class="end">END PAGE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<body>` with the `<div>` tag and add the appropriate css. The pages should have the same class but unique ids. You change the background color with CSS property `background-color`.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class=“page”id=“portfolio”>
</div>
<div class=“page”  id=“about”>
</div>
<div class=“page” id=“contactme”>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.page{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height: auto;
margin:auto;
}
#portfolio{
background-color:white;
}
#about{
background-color:red;
}
#contactme{
background-color:blue;
}
```

Hope this works for you.